# BACPAC backups seem to be stuck

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I'm trying to export my databases and they seem to be "stuck". I tried to create the first backup but when I went download it, I noticed the file size was 0MB. So I went and tried again and got the error below:

> Database export error
>       Failed to export the database: xxxxx-db.
>       ErrorCode: 409
>       ErrorMessage: There is an import or export operation in progress on the database 'xxxxx-db'.

I then tried copying the database into a new database and backing THAT one up. When I checked the database server's "Import/Export History", it shows the following.

It looks like the first backup got stuck at 90% and now it won't even try the second one. And in order to file a support ticket with Microsoft it wants me to pay for a monthly plan. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export?

Answer (score 0):

When the export operation exceeds 20 hours there is a good chance the export has been cancelled. In this case, scale up the tier of the database before beginning the export. Make sure there is no read/write activity on the database. Make sure all large tables have clustered indexes.

Are you trying to export a database of 200 GB or greater? If that is the case export to local storage.

You may have better experience exporting to premium storage.

Sometimes many users exporting databases on the same region may cause some export operations to take more time. Take a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2965554/azure-sql-database-import-export-service-takes-a-long-time-to-import-o) Microsoft Support article.

A workaround that may work in your case, use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to export the database instead of the portal. If you were using SSMS then switch to the portal to perform the export.

1. 1.Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to the Azure SQL Server
3. Right click on the required database, choose "Tasks" and "Export Data-tier Application"